# Create Overlay View on top of UIImagePickerController with Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to create a custom overlay over my UIImagePickerController camera preview screen. I'm not sure how to do this with XCode 6 with the storyboard. I'm using Objective-C.

I have already made the camera preview. I created a UIView in the storyboard, and I used: picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

to create the overlay view. But how do I connect the UIView in my storyboard to the overlay in my code? It seems to me that the UIView always shows up beneath the UIImagePickerController's camera preview. How do I place my custom overlay on "top" of the UIImagePickerController's view?

Thanks

Comment: What I can think of is load the view from a nib file, and then assign it to the cameraOverlayView.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this with using an image png and showing this on top ... Create a class "OverlayView"...

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OverlayView : UIView

@end
```

.m

```
#import "OverlayView.h"

@implementation OverlayView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    //clear the background color of the overlay
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //load an image to show in the overlay

    UIImage *overlayImgae = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"];
    UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                 initWithImage:overlayImage];
    overlayImageView.frame = CGRectMake(115, -20, 815, 815);
    [self addSubview:overlayImageView];

    }

    return self;
    }

    @end
```

Depending on the size of your image change  CGRectMake... Then in the ViewController where you intitialize imagePicker do

```
#import "OverlayView.h"

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];




OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc]
                        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -24.25, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

Again change CGRectMake numbers to fit...

Comment: That's a bad solution. You should use Auto Layout to adapt to different screen sizes

Comment: "Again change CGRectMake numbers to fit..." and by the code above it will always be full screen anyway if he defined SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGTH...? Who needs AL? Do the maths..